# New thread inside lock - c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I need to lock an object (collection), do some operations and call a function that opens a thread using ThreadPool (inside the same lock block).

My question, are the operations performed inside the new thread will still considered thread safe?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx

Comment: Interesting post, thanks L.B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are likely to release the lock before the thread finishes its job, unless you wait for it to exit.

```
lock(collection){
  DoSomeWork();
  LaunchNewThread(); =>  newThread starts
} => the lock will likely be released BEFORE newThread ends
```

So you must wait for newThread to finish before releasing the lock. The ideal solution would be to do everything( the locking and DoSomeWork) inside newThread. If that's not possible, you can create another thread that locks, and waits fot newThread to end:

```
anotherThread{
    lock(collection){
      DoSomeWork();
      LaunchNewThread();
      newThread.JOIN(); => execution will stop until newThread finishes
    } => the lock will be released AFTER newThread returns
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No. The new thread's code runs in its own context, and the `lock` statement (which is really just a convenient way to call [`Monitor.Enter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) operates on a per-thread basis.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at my post here:

http://pilpag.blogspot.dk/2016/04/advanced-programming-easy-way-to-manage.html

In short, use this code:

```
public class LockContainer
{
    private BlockingCollection<object> lockItems { get; set; }

    private object LocalLockItem { get; set; }

    public LockContainer()
    {
        lockItems = new BlockingCollection<object>();
        LocalLockItem = new object();
    }

    public object GetLockItem(string str)
    {
        lock (LocalLockItem)
        {
            if (!lockItems.Any(li => (string)li == str))
            {
                lockItems.Add(str);
            }
            return lockItems.First(li => (string)li == str);
        }
    }
}
```